# how to set text from edit control to a window

Tags: c++

I am trying to grab text from an edit control that I create at runtime and print the text from it onto the parent window (not the title bar) that I also create at runtime.  How do I do this?

```
            const int bufferSize = 1024;
            char textBuffer[bufferSize] = "";

            HWND Editbox = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, "Edit", NULL);
            SendMessage(Editbox, WM_GETTEXT, 
                (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);
            HWND Picbox = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, "Picbox", NULL);

            RECT Picbox_Rect;
            GetClientRect(Picbox,&Picbox_Rect);
            Picbox_Rect.top = 3;
            Picbox_Rect.left = 3;
            hdc = GetDC (Picbox) ;
            HFONT fnt = CreateFont(14,0,0,0,FW_DONTCARE,
                FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                0, VARIABLE_PITCH,TEXT("Verdana"));
            SelectObject(hdc, fnt);
            SetTextColor(hdc,RGB(0,0,255));
            SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
            DrawText(hdc, textBuffer, strlen (textBuffer), 
                &Picbox_Rect, DT_LEFT);
            ReleaseDC (Picbox, hdc) ;
            DeleteObject(fnt);
                //InvalidateRect(Picbox, NULL, TRUE);
```

Comment: Show us some code maybe?

Comment: @eric, The simplest way would be either `GetWindowText` or `WM_GETTEXT` combined with `TextOut`. I'll leave it up to you to customize it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the text out from the edit control and use [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [TextOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to write it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going straight to the Windows API, just use `GetWindowText()` to get the text from the textbox, and `SetWindowText()` to write the text to another window or control.

Comment: I think he doesnt want to write it on Title Bar

Comment: I am using Windows API and I can grab the text with GetWindowText and print it to a Static control just fine with SetWindowText() but I can't seem to get it to print to the main or secondary (child) windows.  I am having no luck printing with TextOut or DrawText.

Comment: @eric, How are you using them? Do you have the right `HDC`, obtained via `GetDC` (remembering to use `ReleaseDC` later)?

Comment: Chris I added GetDC and ReleaseDC and still nothing. Updated my post.

Comment: @eric, you must only call `TextOut` or `DrawText` in response to the WM_PAINT message. Otherwise, your changes can be overwritten.

Comment: @Jonathan, thank you, I had forgotten to place it in WM_PAINT.  I am able to use TextOut to print preset text like "hello world" etc. but still I am unable to print the editbox contents.  Maybe it is something wrong with the way I am handling the textbuffer?

Comment: @eric, I would recommend you cache the value somewhere. I have no idea how your code is set up, but at the point you want to copy the text, you should store it somewhere. What I would probably do is use a lightweight control such as a static control. Then use GetWindowText and SetWindowText to read the text from the textbox and write it to the static control. Thus the thinking behind my original answer.

Comment: @Jonathan, if you are suggesting that I use a static control to print on then I must say that I can't since I am also using a bmp as my background and a static control will not allow bmp as well as text. If you are suggesting something else please elaborate. I tried using a static control but it keeps getting covered (?) by the child window that I am bitmapping and printing to.

Comment: @eric, well again I don't know how your code is setup. If you really can't use a static control (still not convinced), perhaps a custom control would work. And if that won't work, then I would simply recommend that you store the text somewhere, presumably somewhere associated with the window that handles the WM_PAINT message. Then when you get that message, you'll can access the text and pass it to TextOut().

Comment: OK, updated code above. I got the printing sorted out but it only works from a button and I have to comment out the InvalidateRect for it to work.  When I place it in WM_PAINT, which is where it belongs, it does not work whether InvalidateRect is active or not. This puzzles me to say the least.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. If the code you posted is supposed to be responding to WM_PAINT, then it isn't right. You use BeginPaint() to get the HDC, not GetDC().

Comment: No, my code is in a button not WM_PAINT.  I can't get it to work in WM_PAINT with BeginPaint dc. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Well, looks like we've gone full circle then. Add your code outside WM_PAINT and it won't work.